# Unable to write Test

Tags: apex, unit-test, pagereference

I am trying to write a simple test class for redirection.

I want to pass redirect url through vf page .
ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters()

I want to use this and redirect.

I wrote a small test for this and it is giving 0% coverage and 0 tests passed. Please help

This is my Controller class.

```
 global class MyController{

            global Boolean redirect(){
                String oAuthDet = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('oAuthDet');
               if(oAuthDet == 'TEST'){
                return true;
               }
                return false;
            }
    }
```

This is my Test Class :

```
@isTest
public class MyControllerTest{

    static void test_redirect(){
        test.startTest();
        MyController mc = new MyController();
        ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('oAuthDet','TEST');

        mc.redirect();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make your code coverage easier by using `return oAuthDet == 'TEST';` so that you don't have to test both code paths.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of method definition in your test class is wrong.

**Invalid**

`static void test_redirect()`

**Valid**

`static testMethod void test_redirect()`

**OR** as @sfdcfox pointed out.

`@isTest static void test_redirect()`

Below class will give you **100% coverage**:

```
@isTest
public class MyControllerTest{

    static testMethod void  test_redirect(){
        test.startTest();
        ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('oAuthDet','TEST');
        MyController mc = new MyController();

        System.assertEquals(true, mc.redirect());
        test.stopTest();

    }
    static testMethod void  test_redirect2(){
        test.startTest();
        // Set oAuthDet value different to test other part of your code.
        ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('oAuthDet','TEST2');
        MyController mc = new MyController();

        System.assertEquals(false, mc.redirect());
        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, `@isTest static void test_redirect()`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for code coverage : -

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)
public class MyControllerstackTest{

    static testMethod void test_redirect(){
        test.startTest();
        MyControllerstack mc = new MyControllerstack();
        ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('oAuthDet','TEST');
        System.assertEquals( 'TEST', ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oAuthDet'));
        mc.redirect();
        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

It will cover 80%.

Comment: you don't need to write seealldata = false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this test class.

```
@isTest
public class MyControllerTest{

    public static testMethod void test_redirect(){
        Test.startTest();

        PageReference tpageRef = Page.NameOfYourPageHere;//Replace name of your page 'NameOfYourPageHere'
        Test.setCurrentPage(tpageRef);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('oAuthDet', 'TEST');

        System.assertEquals( 'TEST', ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oAuthDet'));

        MyController mc = new MyController();
        System.assertEquals(TRUE, mc.redirect());
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Refer how to add [test class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_test.htm).

Comment: before the 2nd last "}" the line should be  "Test.stopTest();"